# Data type switching when I pass through a function. Lists become floats

Tags: python

So I have this program that consists of 2 classes. One class is a simulated environment that generates data. The other one is the graphic interface. I'm struggling with an issue where I'm trying to pass a list as an argument to the plot_line() function but its changing datatypes. Lists of Lists become regular lists. Lists become floats.

```
#... more code

def plot_data(self):
    self.canvas.delete("all")
    if isinstance(simulated_environment.temperature_data, list):
        print("Sim Env Data is a List")

    print(f"Data Length: {len(simulated_environment.temperature_data)}")

    temperature_realtime = f"Temperature: {simulated_environment.temperature:.2f} Degrees C"
    pressure_realtime= f"Pressure: {simulated_environment.pressure:.2f} kPa"
    humidity_realtime = f"Humidity: {simulated_environment.humidity:.2f} %"

    self.temperature_label.config(text = temperature_realtime)
    self.pressure_label.config(text = pressure_realtime)
    self.humidity_label.config(text = humidity_realtime)
    
    if len(simulated_environment.temperature_data) >= 20:
        print("Plotting Temperature Data")
        print(f"Sim Env: {simulated_environment.temperature_data}")
        self.plot_line(simulated_environment.temperature_data[-20], color = "red", label =          "Temperature") #^^simulated_enviroment.temperature_data is a list^^
        
        
        

def plot_line(self, data, color, label): #data becomes a float here
    print(f"Type of data: {type(data)}")
    

    if not data:
        print("Data is empty")

    if isinstance(data, list):
        print("Data is a List")
        print(f"Length: {len(data)}")
        num_points = len(data)
    else:
        print("Data Fail")
        
    if num_points < 2:
        print("Not enough data to plot")
        
    x_unit = self.canvas.winfo_width() / max(1, num_points - 1)
    y_scale = self.canvas.winfo_height() / max(max(data), 1)


# more code....
```

I'm trying to pass a list through but I end up with a float causing a bunch of unintended errors.

These are the outputs i get from the code above: (The data randomises every 1s and it appends to a list)

```
Temperature: 23.54 °C, Pressure: 102.80 kPa, Humidity: 41.43%
20
Sim Env Data is a List
Data Length: 20
Plotting Temperature Data
Sim Env: [24.604502008798338, 24.48558258335959, 24.618041178534412, 24.157265175906776, 23.864513027637468, 24.060228822631018, 23.711824874315028, 24.031735115808086, 24.44928607244848, 24.784870553465655, 24.482410621617685, 24.291157674992032, 24.59730270592737, 24.74141650850093, 24.384250132551966, 24.51414898090039, 24.385051768565315, 24.382096758035892, 24.025455132023314, 23.537914780551635]
Type of data: <class 'float'>
Data Fail
```

When if len(simulated_environment.temperature_data) >= 20: executes i get this error:

```
 File "c:\Coding\VS Code\Python\Projects\Interface.py", line 83, in plot_line
    num_points = len(data)
                 ^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

I've tried several different things but all my problems are coming from the datatype changing when it's getting passed through the function.

Comment: Something isn't right here. You print `Sim Env: [...]` after `plot_line()` returns, but the output  from `plot_line()` is after that. How did they get out of order?

Comment: You're not passing the whole list to `plot_line()`. You're just passing a single element: `simulated_environment.temperature_data[-20]`

Comment: The datatype isn't changing. It's a list of floats, so `data` is a float.

Comment: Sorry I dont know how that happened 2 lines of code got out of order when i was typing the question i fixed it though

Comment: bit of advice.   Try to trim down unrelated stuff from your example.  Like the label and prints.  Whats relevant is just the isinstances and the call to plot_line.  You’re more likely to get better answers with a minimal example.  And, often, figure it out in the process of writing the minimal code.  Also, use of typing annotations would catch this.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, and yeah I'm pretty sure its the element I've been putting print statements down all over  the place trying to troubleshoot the last few hours so Its a hot mess right now. Gonna see if I can go fix it now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Based on your print statements I'm unsure of the order things were executed in, but I think the issue is this line

```py
 self.plot_line(simulated_environment.temperature_data[-20],...
```

You are only passing the element twentieth from the end of `simulated_environment.temperature_data` into your `plot_line` function, rather than the entire list.

Comment: Thanks I dont know how I missed that guess the "-" symbol threw me off I didn't realize that was the index position. Thank you!!

Comment: @CodingSince2022 yeah, Python allows negative indices, basically, `data[-1]` is the last item, `data[-2]` is the second to last, etc etc

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above by A10, you probably want your list index to be [:20], meaning "start at the beginning and end at the 20th value."

```
>>> var = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> var[:5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you Thank you I spent way too many hours on only having to delete 4 characters :D!!!!